Updating and Improving our Tour/About site
We haven't updated our about page, the Tour, in a long time. I'd like to use this opportunity to clarify the inclusion of other cryptocurrencies on our Site. Please discuss and contribute specific suggestions for improvements you would like to see made.

Why is this tagged faq?

I thought I would make the topic about both tour and faq, but then later changed my mind and forgot to remove the faq tag.

As I said in the discussion you linked to, I think we should either change the name to the Cryptocurrency SE site or alter the rules to focus on Bitcoin and it's sidechains.
The most popular spelling is cryptocurrency, without a hyphen.
If we change the name to remove Bitcoin, we don't have to try an over compensate elsewhere.  I would suggest the following:

Cryptocurrencies is a question and answer site for cryptocurrency enthusiasts. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about cryptocurrencies like Bitcoin.


Good point on the spelling, I changed it. In case you aren't aware: We users can change the content of the site, but not its name. If we want to change the name, we have to get convince the SE staff.
Let's assume that changing the name to cryptocurrencies is not going to happen. Would you rather have a SE that solely focusses on Bitcoin, and no SE for other Cryptos, or make some improvements on Bitcoin.SE so that it is more inclusive to other cryptos? Itˈs not realistic to expect another cryptos SE to take off, which is why I choose to spend my limited time on the second option.

In response to Are we willing to embrace other cryptocurrencies? and previous similar topics, I would like to propose the following changes to our Tour:


Current:

Bitcoin is a question and answer site for Bitcoin and crypto-currency enthusiasts. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Bitcoin.

Proposed:

Bitcoin and Cryptocurrencies is a question and answer site for crypto-currency enthusiasts. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Cryptocurrencies such as e.g. Bitcoin, Namecoin, Litecoin, Ripple, Zerocoin, Dogecoin, Ethereum, and NXT. 




Current:

Ask about...

Specific issues with Bitcoin and other crypto-currencies
Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered


Proposed:

Ask about...

Specific issues with using cryptocurrencies
Algorithms and concepts specific to cryptocurrencies
Any cryptocurrency's sourcecode
Problems with developing applications specific to the cryptocurrency domain
Specific issues with developing new cryptocurrencies
Research into cryptocurrencies





Current:

Don't ask about...

Anything not directly related to bitcoin
Questions that are primarily opinion-based
Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer


Proposed:

Don't ask about...

Anything not directly related to cryptocurrencies
Questions that are primarily opinion-based
Questions that require answers which outdate quickly
Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer




This is an initial effort, I'm looking for feedback!

I didn't realize that the FAQ didn't reflect the current policy. These seem like good changes. ACK

I'll wait a little longer for people to comment. @NickODell: What do you think about the list of examples for Cryptocurrencies. Any to add or drop?

What about other distributed systems that aren't primarily cryptocurrencies, but do involve them? Would a question about OpenBaazar or Storj be on-topic?

Well, if they clearly are based on cryptocurrency, sure why not? If they could function with any other type of payment system, probably not the greatest fit.

ACK the proposed changes.

Pushed the new text to the Tour page.

"Bitcoin and Cryptocurrencies" seems to suggest that Bitcoin isn't covered by the "Cryptocurrency" umbrella. Why not just "Cryptocurrency"? Seems short, sweet, and to the point.

@StephenM347 The site is still titled 'Bitcoin' (we can't change that without staff intervention). I thought that suddenly switching to a completely different title in the next paragraph might be confusing.

@StephenM347 We could phrase it as Bitcoin and Other Cryptocurrencies but that seems a little awkward.

I'd like to propose adding "Investment advice" to the "Do not ask about" section.
Proposed addendum:

Do not ask about…

[…]
Whether, when, or which cryptocurrencies to invest in.



I agree with the idea, (those questions are usually opinion-generating nonsense) but this is probably controversial enough that it ought to be discussed in a separate question.

@NickODell Well, wouldn't be asking e.g. "should I trade my dogecoin for Bitcoin now?", "Should I buy an ASIC?" generally off-topic already due to time-sensitivity. Or are there maybe some questions that would be on-topic that I am not thinking off right now?

Ah, I thought you were talking about "Is X a scam?" type questions. Ok, that seems fine.

What do you think about this: Don't ask about … "Advice what cryptocurrencies to invest in. We can't predict the future."

I've added the line to the "do not ask about".
